# Remember Dropdown Selection

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, menu, html-select, selection

I've got a few select lists on my form which look a bit like this:

```
<option value="400000" <?php if($_GET['MaxPrice'] == "400000") { echo("selected"); } ?>>&pound;400,000</option>
```

As you can see (above) I've got a bit of PHP in there telling the form to remember it's selection upon submit.

Is there a short bit of PHP that would remember every selection without the rather heavy method I'm using above?

UPDATE:

```
<select name="MaxPrice" id="MaxPrice">
    <option value="9999999" selected>Price (Max)</option>
    <option value="100000" <?php if($_GET['MaxPrice'] == "100000") { echo("selected"); } ?>>&pound;100,000</option>
    <option value="200000" <?php if($_GET['MaxPrice'] == "200000") { echo("selected"); } ?>>&pound;200,000</option>
    <option value="300000" <?php if($_GET['MaxPrice'] == "300000") { echo("selected"); } ?>>&pound;300,000</option>
    <option value="400000" <?php if($_GET['MaxPrice'] == "400000") { echo("selected"); } ?>>&pound;400,000</option>
</select>
```

UPDATE 2: Is there a way to implement this technique into some JavaScript?

```
if (BuyRent=='buy')
document.SearchForm.MaxPrice.options[9999999]=new Option("Price (Max)","150000000");
document.SearchForm.MaxPrice.options[100000]=new Option("\u00A3100,000","100000");
document.SearchForm.MaxPrice.options[200000]=new Option("\u00A3200,000","200000");
document.SearchForm.MaxPrice.options[300000]=new Option("\u00A3300,000","300000");
document.SearchForm.MaxPrice.options[400000]=new Option("\u00A3400,000","400000");
```

Comment: That is generally the method I would use.  But you could make a PHP array instead, and loop through the contents of the array, instead of hardcoding a series of <option> tags.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you use some kind of loop. Here's an example :

```
$my_values = array(100000, 200000, 300000, 400000);

foreach($my_values as $value) {
    echo "<option value=\"{$value}\"";
    echo ($_GET['MaxPrice'] == $value) ? 'selected="selected"';
    echo ">" . number_format($value, 0, '.', ',') . "</option>";
}
```

Which would print 4  tags such as `<option value="100000" selected="selected">100,000</option>`.

This code also uses the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), but it's obviously not mandatory, you can write the whole if/else statement if wanted.

**Edit**:

```
<select name="MaxPrice" id="MaxPrice">
    <option value="9999999">Price (Max)</option>
    <?php
    $my_values = array(100000, 200000, 300000, 400000);

    foreach($my_values as $value) {
        echo "<option value=\"{$value}\"";
        echo ($_GET['MaxPrice'] == $value) ? 'selected="selected"' : "";
        echo ">&pound; " . number_format($value, 0, '.', ',') . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Where would I place something like that in my site?

Comment: Instead of manually writing down every `<option>` tag, you use this loop to generate them. So basically, you put this between your `<select>` tag, the same place where you wrote your tags manually. Obviously, you have to replace the values in the array with those you want to use!

Comment: Hmm, it's kind of hard without your code. Could you edit your first message and give us your whole <select> tag (with the <option> tags and everything)?

Comment: Ok I've just done that. I'm new on Stack Overflow so I was a bit baffed on how to add my code in the comment. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! Is there a way to implement that into some JavaScript? I've edited my original post.

Answer (score 0):

good question, it made me wonder if there exists a js plugin to remember form field out there.
[And the answer seems to be "Yes!"](http://rikrikrik.com/jquery/autosave/)